# Updating Model from form in Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, input, view, models

I am creating a simple application using Backbone and Laravel to manage bookings, and I'm working on a simple form to update user data for the currently signed in user.

I was wondering, is there a better, more efficient way than the way I have done, to update your model with the input data from the form?

I have created a method called update in the model, which is passed a DOM object of the form. I assume this isn't the best way to go about it.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

```
var Account = Backbone.Model.extend({

    url: "/settings/account",

    initialize: function()
    {

    },

    update: function(form)
    {
        this.set({
            first_name : form.find('#first-name').val(),
            last_name : form.find('#last-name').val(),
            email : form.find('#email').val(),
            landline: form.find('#landline').val(),
            mobile: form.find('#mobile').val()
        });

        return this.save();
    }

});

var user = new Account;

var AccountView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: $("div.section"),

    template: _.template($("#account-template").html()),

    events: {
        "submit #account": "update"
    },

    initialize: function()
    {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'update');
        this.render();
    },

    render: function()
    {
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    },

    update: function()
    {
        var form = $(this.el).find('form#account');

        user.update(form);

        $(this.el).find('.alert-success').show();

        return false;
    }

});

var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes: {
        "account": "account"
    },

    account: function()
    {
        user.fetch({
            success: function()
            {
                return new AccountView({model:user});
            }
        });         
    }

});
```

Answer (score 6):

It is considered bad design when the model is aware of its view. I would make the update of the model orchestrated by the view.

I think the easiest way would be to do this in the view:

```
update: function()
{
    var form = $(this.el).find('form#account');
    user.set({
        first_name : form.find('#first-name').val(),
        last_name : form.find('#last-name').val(),
        email : form.find('#email').val(),
        landline: form.find('#landline').val(),
        mobile: form.find('#mobile').val()
    });

    user.save();
    $(this.el).find('.alert-success').show();
    return false;
}
```

Otherwise the model would have to know where to retrieve the values. Also, when you someday use a different view you would also have to change the model class.

Comment: I was about to write the same thing. Instead of passing the view to the user, you should pass the user model into the view. Your view can then use the `update()` function to set the values of the user. Otherwise it's pretty good. You can `set()` and save your data in one call (shortcut) by doing `user.save({'attribute':'value'});`

Comment: What triggers the call to "update" on the view? I have a view that binds to a form but I only want to update the model and persist the data using save() after the user clicks a submit button